# how to normalize to 3NF, for example this table about employees, roles, projects and assignments

Tags: database-design, normalization

I'm studying database administration and data modelling as a part of my ICT Apprenticeship course in a Web Development team.

I understand the concept of eliminating redundant data, stopping anomalies and using keys and relationships.

UNF table:

[image: table about employees, roles, projects and assignments, with rows of data]

(Salary is dependent on on role, and time is dependent on project.)

My attempt at normalising the table to 3NF:

[image: tables Employees, Roles, Projects and Assignments, with rows of data]

`Assignments` has Employee ID as a foreign key, meaning Project ID would have to be the primary key. But that seems counter intuitive seeing as `Projects` should be using Project ID as the primary key.

How and why should I have normalized?

Comment: Realize that normalization is a bottom-up design technique, not a top-down one.  In the process of coming up with a new design, it's useful as one way of cross checking a proposed design.  But not all normalized designs are good designs, nor are all good designs normalized ones.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Problem_Solving,_Programming,_Data_Representation_and_Practical_Exercise/Problem_Solving/Top-down_design_and_Step-wise_refinement

Comment: Bottom up means starting with a proposed solution, at the detailed level, and working your way backwards to the big picture.  Bottom-up design is a little like reverse engineering.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Your reasoning is not clear. "Assignments has Employee ID as a foreign key, meaning Project ID would have to be the primary key." Why? "But that seems counter intuitive seeing as Projects should be using Project ID as the primary key." Why? Every base table has its own FDs, CKs (including PK) & FKs. What published normalization reference are you following, what did you start with, what steps did you take and where/how are you 1st stuck/unsure following it? [ask] [Help] It is pointless to worry about things you happen to notice or wonder, just apply the definitions & procedures you were given.

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at an example of a table is a *wrong* way of normalizing. You should *understand* the meaning of the fields to properly normalize. For instance you should know if the salary is the same for all the persons that have a certain role, or if it differs from person to person (in the above example we cannot know, since each role has only a person, so that *both* interpretations are possible).

To know the meaning of the properties you have two routes: either know the meaning of the elements of the domain, through a high level model of it, (for instance through an Entity-Relationship model or a UML model), or to have formalized this knowledge through the definition of the functional dependencies holding between the properties.

In your example there are two points that are not clear (that this that are not clear from the example table): is the salary related to a role or to a person? Is the Est. Time related to a project or to the fact that an employee works for a certain project for that estimated time? If the correct anwer to those question is the first one in both cases, your schema is correct (or normalized). Otherwise you must revise it.

Comment: Asking "is the salary related to a role or to a person?" is typical & appealing but unhelpful. Presentations in such vague & misconceived terms are why people are confused.  ("Meaning" not meaning "relationship predicate" is problematic too.) Every query expression returns the rows satisfying a certain relation/relationship/association. Everything is related to everything else in unlimited ways. The question in DB design is, what relationships are of interest & how do business & world rules constrain participation in them. Make every tutorial statement a paraphrase of an identified formal one.